# Error al guardar imagen desde el portapapeles

Tags: python

Estoy intentando guardar una imagen con **opencv** desde el portapapeles y usando conjuntamente la librería `clipboard`. Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```
frame = clipboard.paste()
carpeta=('Data'+'.jpg')
cv2.imwrite(carpeta,frame)
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
 File "recortes.py", line 39, in <module>
    cv2.imwrite(carpeta,frame)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'img'
```

Verifiqué el tipo de datos que tiene el portapapeles cuando tiene una imagen y resultó ser `string`.

Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: Alexander, ¿Es posible que agregues un trozo de código que podamos probar? El que has puesto no funciona a la primera. De paso te comento que, según entiendo, **clipboard** sólo trabaja con texto.

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, gracias por tu comentario ya realice las modificaciones pertinentes, con las cuales se debería poder correr el código a la primera. Lo que deseo hacer es guardar una imagen que esta en el portapapeles desde python he estado investigando y encontré la librería **Pillow**  pero esta solo funciona en _Windows_ y estoy usando _Ubunto 16.04_

Comment: Seguro que el portapapeles no tiene la ruta o el base64 de la imagen?